# How to install CU in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, upgrade, installation, service-pack

I have a SharePoint server with the following build version,

Version : 14.0.4763.1000.

Under **Manage Patch Status** I can find the following products with the same above mentioned version,

1. Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010
2. Microsoft® Office Web Apps
3. Microsoft® Project Server 2010

Now I need to install the December 2012 CU, I read that December 2012 CU is a Post-SP1 hotfix,

1. Should I install both the SharePoint foundation SP1 and SharePoint Server SP1 and whats the order of installation?
2. How to find which all language packs are installed in the server.?
3. Should I install both the SharePoint foundation december 2012 CU and SharePoint Server december 2012 CU and whats the order of installation?
4. As I can see Project server 2010 in the sever Should I go for "SharePoint Server 2010 with Project Server December 2012 CU" ?
5. What about the Office web apps, what all to be installed for it to be upgraded.?

Kindly request you to provide me the links for downloads and steps for the installation to proceed further.

Answer (score 2):

1. It'll state that on the installation instructions
2. You'll find installed language packs in "Programs and Features" in Control Panel
3. See 1.
4. Yes. Also see 1.
5. Office Web Apps is a separate Microsoft Product so updates for that are delivered through the OWA portal on TechNet. Here's instructions on installing updates: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj966220.aspx

At time of posting, SP2 is the most recent version. It's highly recommended you install that over SP1. Find that here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2687453/en-gb and read the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

From the version number you mentioned in your question, you are on RTM version.
here are steps which i would do to update the farm.
From Central admin go the Manger Server in the farm, Note down all the Language Packs if you have any for SharePoint.

Download SP1 for SharePoint Foundation 2010 & SharePoint Server 2010 & Project Server 2010.
Download SP1 for each Language Packs installed  Both Foundation & Server.

Download the SP2 for the SharePoint Project Server 2010( will include all Foundation & Server & project Server).

Download SP2 for each Language Packs installed  Both Foundation & Server.

Download the Latest CU( Dec Cu 2013) for Project Server 2010.

Now Install in this order:
1) Install SP1 Foundation on all servers > Sp1 Server On all servers > SP1 Project Server on all server. Now Install SP1 Foundation for All Installed Language Packs > SP1 server for All Installed Language Packs.

2) Install SP2 for Project server, Now Install SP2 Foundation for All Installed Language Packs > SP2 server for All Installed Language Packs.

3) Install Decu CU 2013 for project server 2010.

Go to follwoing blog having link to all available SP1 & CUs.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2010/09/29/build-numbers-cube-sheet-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx